# Add dynamically objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, dynamically-generated

I'm implementing a pacman game. One condition is that you have to add or remove enemies in runtime (while playing). My idea is to add a ghost when you press '+' and remove a ghost every time you press '-'.

Im using opengl to draw the maze and characters. I don't know how to make a new ghost(); or delete ghost(); every time you press the keys mentioned above.

Perhaps another solution would be a vector or map of ghosts. But user would not give any name or anything...

My pseudo code:

```
#define MOVE 1
#define QUIET 2

class particle {

protected: //Antes era publica

  float x,y;   //-- Current position
  float vx,vy; //-- Velocity vector
  int state;

  long time_remaining;

public:

  particle();
  void set_position(int x,int y);
  void init_movement(int destination_x,int destination_y,int duration);
  void integrate(long t);
  void draw();
  virtual ~particle();
};
#endif /* PARTICLE_H_ */
```

Ghost would be an inherited class of a particle.

I control the keyboard input in the window of the game with following code (i put some code to get the idea):

```
glutDisplayFunc(display);

     //TO-DO : COMMENT
     glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);


     glutSpecialFunc(specialkeyboard);
```

Finally here when gamer presses the key '+' to add a ghost to the game...

```
void specialkeyboard(int key,int x,int y)
{

    switch(key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            //Pacman moves up
            goNorth();
            //square.set_position(300,300);
            //square.init_movement(300,500,1000);
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            //Pacman moves down
        //  square.set_position(300,300);
        //  square.init_movement(300,100,1000);
            goSouth();
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            //Pacman moves to the left
            goEast();
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            goWest();
            //square.set_position(300,300);
            //square.init_movement(500,300,1000);
            break;
    case '+':
          //generate new ghost some kind of ( add ghost to the game)
          new ghost();
          break;
    case '-':
              //kill or remove ghost from the game
              delete ghost;
              break;

        }

  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Im programming with Eclipse and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps another solution would be a vector or map of ghosts

Exactly.

> But user would not give any name or anything...

Since when do you need a name to `push_back` to `vector`?

Of course, I wouldn't use pointers in this case; just push or pop a value. In case you really wanted to use pointers, don't use raw ones and `new`/`delete`; a `vector` or `set` of `std::unique_ptr<your_type>` will be a much better choice.

Comment: I prefer not using STL containers in my rendering stuff.

Comment: I use stl container for most things, but for renderings loops I use very simple containters, because I do a lot of assembn

Comment: @ChristianDyrnesli, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @ChristianDyrnesli "because I do a lot of assembn" is hardly a valid reason for me.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, tags don't include C++14, and I doubt we should consider it default at this time.

Comment: @SergeyA which one of the **previous** standards, namely 98, 03 or 11 should be considered then? C++14 is the **current** standard and I see no reason to **not** assume it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, while this is, of course, subjective, I believe it's reasonable to assume C++11 unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: two questions you cant write a simple pushback() ghost... you have to count them and put something like myvector.push_back(g); where g is a ghost...isnt it ? i wouldnt know that name of ghost g. And if i want to draw with opengl that ghost, i would do someghing like myvector[0].draw(); ( suppose draw a public function of class ghost). Thanks

Comment: @EduardoGutierrez If you want the "name" associated with each one, you should use a `map` or an `unordered_map`, but I'd say it might not be necessary. And yeah, if you wanted to draw all of them, a loop over all of them would do - jus remember about range-for.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz so if i understand you, id have a variable ghost g with the actual ghost and then add it to the vector with something like myvector.pushback(g); and delete it with myvector.pop(g);....and how to access every "ghost" myvector[i].draw()... as said before draw is a function/operation of the class ghost. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not `new` your ghosts. Have a vector of `ghost` objects, and push_back an entry to the vector every time you want to make a player's life harder. When '-' is pressed, you will simply `pop_back` from the vector (just make sure you have at least one element there before popping).